# How can I extract a pdf faster with tabulizer in R

Tags: r, csv, pdf, tabulizer

I have a table in a pdf file with more than 100000 rows and over 1900 pages which I decided to write into a .csv file with the R package `tabulizer`.

When I try to exctract the whole data from the pdf file with

```
pdf <- extract_tables("pdffile.pdf", method = "csv")
```

I get an error,

> error in .jcall("rjavatools", "ljava/lang/object;", "invokemethod", cl, : java.lang.outofmemoryerror: gc overhead limit exceeded

Therefore I followed another approach.

What I did was to extract a page of the pdf one by one, and save the output as 
a .csv file.

1) get the number of pages of the pdf file

```
pdfPages <- length(get_page_dims("pdffile.pdf"))
```

2) Create a for loop to store a .csv file for each page.

```
for (i in 1:pdfPages) {
    page <- extract_tables("pdffile.pdf", pages = i, method = "data.frame")
    write.csv(page, file = paste(i,".csv", sep = ""))
}
```

3) Then created another loop for reading each file by one, and rbind it
to the next one.

```
dataPdf  <- data.frame() # to rbind each .csv file
for (i in c(1:pdfPages)){
    page <- read.csv(paste(i,".csv", sep = ""))
    dataPdf <- bind_rows(dataQuilpue, page) 
}
```

I had to use `bind_rows()`from the `dplyr`package since not all .csv files
ended with the same number of columns.

The result was more than satisfactory, though it took about 1.75 hours to complete, so I was thinking that maybe there is a better way to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `fread`, `fwrite`, and `rbindlist` from `data.table`.

Comment: The thing is, that, in the first loop, the function that takes a lot of time is `extract_tables()`. The difference in time between running the loop with `write.csv` or `fwrite` is minimun, so my question is, if there is a way to make use of the tabulizer in a better way, tomake it faster.

Comment: you would do well to phrase your question more succinctly as such

Comment: Can you give an example of a PDF for which you can to do this?